# SpringBoot in Docker not connecting to Mongo and throws Exception

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have three Microservices with three databases for them, such as player-db, game-db and score-db.
For each of these services I defined Dockerfile in their folders.
(DockerFiles are the same just the name of JAR file and container_name are different)
DockerFile for Score service:

```
 FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar score.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://score-container-db:27017/","-jar","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1", "score.jar"]
```

I must pointed that, all my services packages are sub-packages of:

```
package spring.multiple.mongo.project;
```

which is my Application, by the way, in my Applicaton I used
 @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
for AutoConfiguration.
My Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "3"
services:
    player-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/player/DockerFile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
    game-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/game/DockerFile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8082:8080
        depends_on:
            - db1
    score-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/score/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8083:8080
        depends_on:
            - db2 
    db:
        image: mongo
        container_name: player-container-db
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: player-mongo-db
    db1:
        image: mongo
        container_name: game-container-db
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db1
        ports:
            - 27018:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: game-mongo-db
    db2:
        image: mongo
        container_name: score-container-db
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db2
        ports:
            - 27019:27017
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: score-mongo-db
volumes:
    mongodata:
```

My application.properties:

```
    spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=player-db
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data1.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data1.mongodb.database=game-db
spring.data1.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data2.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data2.mongodb.database=score-db
spring.data2.mongodb.port=27017
```

The problem is, when i run docker-compose up, when start SpringBoot part, for all my services,it shows me an error:

```
 score-docker_1   | 2020-06-14 17:08:17.698  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mon
godb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting
 to server localhost:27017
score-docker_1   |
score-docker_1   | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socke
t
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:70) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnect
ion.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$
ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.1
1.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Con
nection refused)
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPl
ainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Abs
tractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlai
nSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java
:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_2
52]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.in
itialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initiali
zeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      ... 3 common frames omitted
score-docker_1   |
game-docker_1    | 2020-06-14 17:08:19.260  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c
oncurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTas
kExecutor'
game-docker_1    | 2020-06-14 17:08:20.490  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w
.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with
context path ''
score-docker_1   | 2020-06-14 17:08:19.751  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c
oncurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTas
kExecutor'
score-docker_1   | 2020-06-14 17:08:20.776  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w
.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with
context path ''
game-container-db | 2020-06-14T17:07:55.286+0000 I  COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCach
eRefresh] command config.system.sessions command: createIndexes { createIndexes:
 "system.sessions", indexes: [ { key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", expi
reAfterSeconds: 1800 } ], $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:114 locks:{ Paralle
lBatchWriterMode: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, ReplicationStateTransition: { acqu
ireCount: { w: 3 } }, Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 2 } }, Database: { acqu
ireCount: { r: 1, w: 2, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4, w: 1, R: 1
, W: 2 } }, Mutex: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } } } flowControl:{ acquireCount: 1, t
imeAcquiringMicros: 1 } storage:{} protocol:op_msg 1880ms
score-container-db | 2020-06-14T17:07:55.232+0000 I  COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCac
heRefresh] command config.system.sessions command: createIndexes { createIndexes
: "system.sessions", indexes: [ { key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", exp
ireAfterSeconds: 1800 } ], $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:114 locks:{ Parall
elBatchWriterMode: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, ReplicationStateTransition: { acq
uireCount: { w: 3 } }, Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 2 } }, Database: { acq
uireCount: { r: 1, w: 2, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4, w: 1, R:
1, W: 2 } }, Mutex: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } } } flowControl:{ acquireCount: 1,
timeAcquiringMicros: 1 } storage:{} protocol:op_msg 1826ms
```

and in the Postman:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.99.100:8080
```

I tried too many things, I read too many documents but I could not find any solution.
Also, I am beginner in Docker.
In addition, I tried set spring.data.mongo.host = "To the service name in docker compose" and set the spring.data.mongo.port = " to the port of service" like:

```
 spring.data.mongodb.host=player-container-db
spring.data.mongodb.database=player-db
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data1.mongodb.host=game-container-db
spring.data1.mongodb.database=game-db
spring.data1.mongodb.port=27018
spring.data2.mongodb.host=score-container-db
spring.data2.mongodb.database=score-db
spring.data2.mongodb.port=27019
```

but nothing changed and I have error as before.!

Comment: you can inspect the docker network

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev could you tell me how?! because i am not familier with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about somthings:
1- I forgot each time i do some change on my application, I must rebuild the JAR file.
2- the volume for all my databases was the same and it cuased the over-wrighting and because of this one mongo could not find others(databases), so for each one I use different volumes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the mongo connection uri as `mongodb://<docker-container-name>:<port>`? For example, in player docker you would have the uri as `mongodb://player-docker:27017`.

Comment: yes I did, but for all I used 27017. for example for game-container-db:27017 and after that I tried this: player-container-db:27017 and game-container-db:27018 and score-container-db:27019. but errores are same as before

Comment: Can you print the connection uri used to connect from each service?